Is is possible to pass USB to docker-android container?
Has anyone had any luck passing a USB device to docker-android container? I am trying to pick up data from a temperature/humidity sensing device that pushes data over USB. The device works fine on an actual phone but not in a container. Have tried using:
sudo docker run -d -t -i --device=/dev/bus/usb/001/001 -p 6080:6080 -e EMULATOR_DEVICE="Samsung Galaxy S9" -e WEB_VNC=true --device /dev/kvm budtmo/docker-android:emulator_10.0

and have also tried using:
sudo docker run -d -t -i --privileged -v /dev/bus/usb/001/001:/dev/bus/usb/001/001 -p 6080:6080 -e EMULATOR_DEVICE="Samsung Galaxy S9" -e WEB_VNC=true --device /dev/kvm budtmo/docker-android:emulator_10.0

Both commands don't throw any errors and boot up an instance of docker-android but do not appear to be actually passing USB data in. Base OS running Docker is Ubuntu 22.04.
Does anyone have any ideas how to do this or at least some ideas on debugging?
